# $\partial I^2/\sim$ is the wedge of two cirlces

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

So Im trying to calculate the $\pi_1$ of a perforated Torus, and Im trying to do it the most detailed as posible. So I got to show that the perforated torus deformation retracts to $\partial I^2/\sim$ where $(x,0)\sim(x,1)$ and $(0,y)\sim(1,y)$. So now I want to show that $\partial I^2/\sim \ =S^1\vee S^1$ and here is where I'm having some trouble in writing this last statement.

Could some one give me a hint in how to write this as formally as possible?

Comment: Define an onto mapping from $\partial I^2$ to $S^1\vee S^1$, that is constant on the equivalence classes. This induces a map from the quotient space to $S^1\vee S^1$. Show this map is injective, then use the Hausdorff / compactness to show this is a homeomorphism.

Comment: Something like sending $I \times \{0\}$ and $I\times \{1\}$ to $S_1$, $\{0\} \times  I$ and $\{1\} \times I$ to $S_2$ such that the map is continuous (using the pasting lemma) might work?

Comment: That will do it!